# ¿Cómo obtener último id insertado si la consulta está en otro archivo?

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli

alguien sabe cómo puedo obtener el último id insertado si la consulta se encuentra en otro archivo?

Tengo lo siguiente:

class.php

```
class Conectar{
 public static function con(){
  $conexion = mysqli_connect("localhost","x","");
  mysqli_query($conexion,"SET NAMES 'utf8'");
  mysqli_select_db($conexion,"eventos");
  return $conexion;
 }
}

class Datos{

 public function add_evento($n_evnt,$tipo_evento){
  $sql = "INSERT INTO evnts VALUES (null,'$n_evnt',$tipo_evento)";

  $res = mysqli_query(Conectar::con(),$sql);
 } 

}
```

En formulario.php incluyo a class.php y hago lo siguiente:

```
$evento = new Datos();
$evento->add_evento($_POST['n_evnt'], $_POST['tipo_evento']);
```

He leído que utilizando el estilo orientado a objetos se debe utilizar **insert_id**, pero los ejemplos que he encontrado, incluso en la documentación de PHP la consulta y el uso de insert_id están en el mismo archivo.

He intentado con esto:

```
echo $evento->insert_id;
```

Está completamente mal, pero no tengo ni idea.

¿Alguna sugerencia?

Saludos.

Comment: No hay ningún problema al realizar el insert.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Puedes hacer uso de `LAST_INSERT_ID()` para obtener el ultimo indice auto incrementable.

```
SELECT LAST_INSERT_ID() FROM evnts;
```

Puedes leer la referencia en [MySQL LAST_INSERT_ID() Function](https://www.w3schools.com/sql/func_mysql_last_insert_id.asp#:%7E:text=The%20LAST_INSERT_ID()%20function%20returns,or%20updated%20in%20a%20table.)

Nada mas modifica un poco tu clase `Datos`

```
class Datos{

    private $n_evnt;
    private $tipo_evento;
    public $res;
 
    function __construct($n_evnt,$tipo_evento){
        $this->n_evnt = $n_evnt;
        $this->tipo_evento = $tipo_evento;
    }

    public function add_evento(){
        $sql = "INSERT INTO evnts VALUES (null,'$this->n_evnt',$this->tipo_evento)";
        $this->res = mysqli_query(Conectar::con(),$sql);
        return $this->res;
    } 
    
    function getLastInserted(){
        $sql = "SELECT LAST_INSERT_ID() FROM evnts";
        $this->res = mysqli_query(Conectar::con(),$sql);
        return $this->res;
    }
}
```

y lo instancias de la siguiente manera

```
$evento = new Datos($n_evnt,$tipo_event);
if($evento->add_evento()){
   $lastID = $evento->getLastInserted();
   /*CODIGO CUANDO SE INSERTO Y TRAS OBTENER EL ID*/
}
/*CODIGO CUANDO NO SE INSERTO*/
```

puedes leer como hacer clases y objetos en [Clases y objetos](https://www.php.net/manual/es/language.oop5.php)

## Edicion

Para mejorar el funcionamiento de las consultas se puede separar cada componente de la siguiente manera

```
<?php /*CONNECT.PHP*/
    
    function OpenCon(){
    
         $dbhost = "localhost";
         $dbuser = "usuario";
         $dbpass = "contra";
         $db = "base";
    
         $conn = new mysqli($dbhost, $dbuser, $dbpass,$db);
    
         if($conn === false){
            die("ERROR: Could not connect. " . mysqli_connect_error());
        }
    
         return $conn;
    }
         
    function CloseCon($conn){
         mysqli_close($conn);
    }
    
?>
class Datos{ /*eventos.php*/

    requiere_once("connect.php");        

    private $con;
    private $n_evnt;
    private $tipo_evento;
    public $res;

    function __construct($n_evnt,$tipo_evento){
        $this->n_evnt = $n_evnt;
        $this->tipo_evento = $tipo_evento;
        $this->con = OpenCon();
    }

    public function add_evento(){
        $sql = "INSERT INTO evnts VALUES (null,?,?)";
        $stmt = $this->con->prepare($sql);
        $stmt->bind_params("ss",$this->n_evnt,$this->tipo_evento);
        $stmt->execute();
        $result = $stmt->affected_rows();
        $this->res = $result ? "Se inserto con exito": "No se inserto";   
        $stmt->close();
        return $this->res;
    } 

    function getLastInserted(){
        $sql = "SELECT LAST_INSERT_ID() FROM evnts";
        $stmt = $this->con->prepare($sql);
        $stmt->execute();
        $result = $stmt->affected_rows;
        $this->res = $result ? $stmt->fetch_assoc():Array("error"=>"NO se pudo obtener el ID");
        $stmt->close();
        return $this->res;
    }

    function __destruct(){
         CloseCon($this->con);
    }
}
```

E instancias de la misma manera solo cambias lo siguiente

```
$evento = new Datos($n_evnt,$tipo_event);
if($evento->add_evento()){
   $lastID = $evento->getLastInserted();}
   var_dump($lastID);
   unset($evento); /*Se destruye una vez encontrado el ID*/
   /*CODIGO CUANDO SE INSERTO Y TRAS OBTENER EL ID*/
}
unset($evento); /*Se destruye si no se encontro el ID*/
/*CODIGO CUANDO NO SE INSERTO*/
```

Comment: Hola, muchas gracias por responder.. he implementado tu código y cuando quiero mostrar la variable $lastID con un echo, obtengo esto: Recoverable fatal error: Object of class mysqli_result could not be converted to string in....
Creo que se tiene que pasar por un while, así lo hago y me muestra esto: 000000000000
no sé qué pasa :(

Comment: El insert lo realiza sin problema alguno.

Comment: Esa cantidad de ceros corresponde al número de registros que ya tengo en la tabla... Pero sigo sin obtener el último id insertado :(

Comment: Ya esta la modificacion amigo, revisa que esta todo en POO